# html-webpack-plugin with pug-loader not picking up options

Tags: webpack, html-webpack-plugin, pug-loader

Consider:

```
plugins: [
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: 'index.pug',
    title: 'Page Title',
    custom: 'Custom'
  })
]
```

Inside `index.pug`:

```
doctype html
html
  head
    meta(charset="utf-8")
    meta(http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge")
    meta(name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1")
    title= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title
```

I would expect the custom title to get picked up, but it outputs the default `Webpack App` instead (and the `custom` variable is `undefined`).

- webpack 1.15.0
- html-web-pack-plugin 2.30.1
- pug 2.0.0-rc.4

I'm at my wits' end here, and I get the feeling it's something obvious I missed.

Comment: `htmlWebpackPlugin` option only works in `.ejs` file.

Comment: @imcvampire seriously? Is that documented somewhere?

Comment: It only supports `ejs` by default. But you can config to use another loader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change your config to:

```
plugins: [
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: '!!pug-loader!index.pug',
    title: 'Page Title',
    custom: 'Custom'
  })
]
```

Read more about this https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/blob/master/docs/template-option.md#2-setting-a-loader-directly-for-the-template

Comment: And also, I was only reloading the dev-server, and not the watcher, so my config changes weren't being picked up at all... duh!

Comment: My suggestion about this problem is you should use some file watcher (nodemon, ...) to reload when you have a new config.